# why templateCache not working in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to use $templateCache.But when I  console using **$templateCache.get()** it give me undefined ..why ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/MAXQmzTVR8fpsw645rct?p=preview

```
<script>
      angular.module('app',[ ]).directive('h',function($templateCache){
        console.log($templateCache.get('about.html'))
        var element=angular.element('<input type="text" ng-model="message"><div>{{message}}</div>');
       return { restrict:'E',
        scope:{},
        templateUrl:'a.html',replace:true,
        transclude:true,
        compile:function(tElement){
          tElement.append(element);
          return function(s,e,a){
            s.$watch('message',function(val){
             // console.log('------'+val)
            })
          }
        }


       }
      })
    </script>



        **console.log($templateCache.get('about.html'))** give me undefined why ?
```

Comment: First, try to format your code :).

Comment: First you should `$templateCache.put('about.html','<div></div>')` before execute `$templateCache.get('about.html')` and where is about.html in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because currently you are running that statement while registering that directive. That time `$templateCache` don't have the templates in it.
You need to put that line inside directive `compile` function then only you will get data in it.

Comment: could you please give plunker?

Answer (score 0):

See this question I think this should help you

[Angular Tabs render templates with caching in "ng-include src"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972339/angular-tabs-render-templates-with-caching-in-ng-include-src/32985506#32973483)

template is  is loaded in the template cache for quick retrieval. 
You can load templates by $templateCache service directly.

```
angular.module('app', []).run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('a.html');
});
```

To retrieve simply use it in your HTML

```
<div ng-include=" 'a.html' "></div>
```

or

```
$templateCache.get('a.html')
```